# How to understand call signature in such a case?

Tags: typescript

I'm a newbie to typescript, so confused about the call signature.
In the following code, there's an interface Counter, it's supposed a function type and has some additional properties *interval* and *reset*.
I don't understand this statement:
`let counter = function (start: number) {} as Counter;`
The variable *counter* is a function return undefined, then we use type assertion here, so the function *counter* has a Counter type?
In Counter interface, the function has a parameter start and return string, but for
`let counter= function (start: number) {}` , this function declaration return undefined, but the complier doesn't throw any errors,  can anyone please explain this to me?

```
interface Counter {
  (start: number): string;
  interval: number;
  reset(): void;
}
function getCounter(): Counter {
  let counter = function (start: number) {} as Counter;
  counter.interval = 123;
  counter.reset = function () {};
  return counter;
}
let c = getCounter();c(10);c.reset();c.interval = 5.0;
```

Comment: I'm no good with Python, but `(start: number)` I feel like you might need to place a digit where the number is like this `(start: 1)`. Is this the script that you are using as is, Do you have the original layout, and the edited version. Can you give examples on what your goal is

Comment: 1. Welcome to SO. 2. Please post code as text, not as image. (In case of TS, ideally add playground link) 3. Counter is a call signature. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures 4. Presented code tries to ctreate an intance of Counter with a type assertion. 5. It fails to do so, as initial function returns undefined instead of string. 6. The error is masked by the type assertion.

Comment: "but the complier doesn't throw any errors" --- `as` type cast is not absolutely type safe, and in some cases (like this) it may cause troubles.

Comment: There are use-cases for [type assertion](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion) (`as TYPE`). This is not one. You should create a class implementing the interface, and create an instance of that one without type assertion.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript isn't perfect because it's actually really hard to layer static types onto such a dynamic language.

The problem here is that you can't create a function that also has custom properties in a single statement. So the typecast that is `as Counter` here tells typescript "this may not be typesafe, but please treat this function as a `Counter` anyway."

Doing this allows you to then right to the properties that only would exist if that function was assumed to be a `Counter` function. However, this also potentially glosses over other type errors, like the return type of the function being wrong.

---

In summary, the reason that no type errors are thrown is that when you use `as` you tell typescript that you know better than the compiler, and therefore some type errors are suppressed.

Comment: "this may not be typesafe, but please treat this function as a Counter anyway." It's interesting. How is it possible to treat a function return undefined as an instance of Counter? So using as keyword, typescript ignores the error and but variable counter still is a function return undefined?